# Debugging in Intellij While using Gradle

Tags: java, debugging, gradle, intellij-idea

So, I believe I am missing something with Intellij.
Sometimes I am able to debug my code, other times I am not.
I am not sure why?  I know I am using Gradle to pull my dependencies and to run through some tasks in my build.gradle file.  Is that building my project in a different directory than what intellij is looking for when debugging locally? 
My Question is How can I consistently use the Run, Debugg tools in intellij and gradle at the same time?

Btw: I followed these links to set my project to auto-compile:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/compiler.html
and
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/problems-tool-window.html

But I find IntelliJ's site to be really confusing and outdated in lots of places.

Answer (score 0):

So I closed out of the project and reimported the project, making sure to overwrite the .iml file.
That seemed to work.  Hope this helped somebody.  I am still confused why I had to do this though feel free to answer if you have any clues.